# Difference between "провокационный" and "провокативный"

Tags: прилагательные

The dictionaries list **provocative** in both cases... I'm wondering if there's any difference.

Comment: Провокативный is used in the context connected with psychology and psychotherapy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Провокационный` is an older borrowing from the Latin through German, while `провокативный` is borrowed from English is way new - it started to be used at the end of XXth century.

While `провокативный` is gaining some popularity (I guess because it's just shorter) it's nowhere near as widely used as `провокационный`.

As far as I know, they are completely interchangeable though.

Comment: "провокативный" is not a word to use at decent society of educated people

Comment: @ArtemDudkin довольно провокативное заявление!

Comment: По-моему, не стоит говорить о том, что такое слово вообще существует. Да, его произносят на ТВ безграмотные журналисты, но слышно ли его на улице и в разговорах? Нет, конечно.

Comment: @ArtemDudkin существует всё, что произнесено, по факту оно используется, нравится нам или нет - пытаться урегулировать словооупотребление - занятие неблагодарное. Меня тоже бесят многие слова, что ж теперь.

Comment: Помимо сочетаний букв, которые можно произнести, есть еще и практика употребления слова, так ведь? Например, слова 'автомобиль', 'транспортное средство', 'самобеглая коляска', 'моя колымага' и 'ржавое ведро' - синонимы, однако имеют разные оттенки и употребляются в разных случаях. Первое покрывает 90% всех смыслов и чаще всего употребляется. Второе - используется в правилах дорожного движения и прочих официальных бумагах и т. д. Своим комментарием я попытался очертить границы и контекст применения слова 'провокативный', только и всего.

Comment: @ArtemDudkin вы ошибаетесь

Comment: These words are not interchangeable.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs then just provide your own answer to refute my claim

Comment: Others already have, more or less. But if I had to explain it, 'провокативный' is a recent calque from English and may be either a careless or illiterate translation, or have an established use in a certain contexts like psychology or psychotherapy, as noted by V.V. in a comment to the original question (and that use may possibly originate from a careless translation).

Answer (score 7):

I hardly ever heard the word "провокативный", and it is not listed in most dictionaries, while "провокационный" is a common word. To translate "provocative" you can use "провокационный" only when it refers to something that leads to conflict, fight or polemic. For other meanings word "вызывающий" fits better.

Answer (score 3):

**Провокационный** is usually about *something* (supposedly) done intentionally in order to get an expected reaction.

**Провокативный** can be either about something *potentially* provocative (able to cause some undesired reaction, not necessarily intended), or (by extension of the term used in psychology*) about *someone* who tends to behave in a provocative way.

- http://azps.ru/handbook/conflict/provokativnosty.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say, провокационный can refer to some action or doing such as military maneuvers or accusation while провокативный to things, like sexy clothing or unusual design.